# What tricks are possible when playing PES 2010 on a keyboard?

Tags: pc, pro-evolution-soccer-2010

I have been playing PES 2010 for a long time now, but being a hardcore PC gamer I never really got to grips with a gamepad. I am much better playing with a keyboard, but it seems that to do some of the nicest tricks you need the analog controls found on a pad. Are there any interesting / effective tricks that can be done on a keyboard without breaking one's fingers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this video tutorial:

!